# Автоматический запуск программы под root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ос

Нужно, чтоб программа автоматически запускалась под root (по нажатию на иконку приложения), без консольного ввода sudo

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sudo+nopasswd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo chown root:root имя_файла
sudo chmod u+s,g+s имя_файла
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, очень помогли